# Restart pip and Python on mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I've installed Python using Homebrew and with the system install and I have been using the system version with pip. But I've been trying to use Homebrew and can't figure out how since everything is set to the system folder in the library. I've changed the pip install location and I am getting errors every time I try to install something. How can I pretty much delete pip and Python and restart this whole process and not mess everything up again? I am using MacOS.

Comment: "everything is set to the system folder in library". Do you mean the appropriate directory has not been added to `PATH`, so that the Homebrew-installed packages are not visible?

Answer (score 1):

For each new project or playground you can create a new virtual environment, activate it and install packages.. something like this:

```
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip 
pip install <package>
```

every time you need to work on your project or run it

```
# cd project/path/...
source venv/bin/activate
python main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try manually installing python through https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/ or through brew from https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/